# Can "drawed" UI like this be done in MFC

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, wtl

I've recently found a lightweight IM, called WTW. It looks like this:

[image: screen]
<sub>(source: [download.wtw.im](http://download.wtw.im/images/image1.png))</sub>

Now, I wonder if that kind of interfaces can be done in plain MFC.
Thanks.

Comment: sure can but would take a hell of a lot of building... just use wpf

Comment: Have a look at this question previously asked...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751685/creating-a-gui-with-mfc

Comment: @PaulSullivan ah, thank you. But, do you know any website/book that I could use to learn how to build such ui?

Comment: do you still want to build it from scratch? If so any standard c++ book has enough for you to do it. As long as you can a) display a window b) draw circles, squares, text, gradients etc c) track the mouse position and gestures then you can do anything you want. But it will take a LOOOONG time. You are better off learning Windows Presentation Foundation which has already done all of the grunt work for you

Comment: @PaulSullivan Well, it's funny because I am actually thinking about switching from .NET/WPF to more "native" way of doing application development. But now it does not seem like a good idea. Thank you for that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can be.  MFC supports [custom controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk2h3c6w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and drawing, so you can make any user interface you choose.

While this may be simpler using other technologies, it is definitely *possible* in MFC.

Comment: anything is possible but not plausible without large budget and a lot of experience.